# How to delete internal style (<style></style>) with bash script or command?

Tags: html, bash, sed, automation, scripting

I'm working on my final automation to use CriticalCSS in every html page a project/folder has.

So far i was able to get so far to get criticalCSS into every html page with this workflow:
https://github.com/Macleykun/voxsiren.net/blob/main/.github/workflows/criticalCSS.yml

However, the only problem i'm having is that if new html is added/changed. And thus the criticalCSS changes.

1. The criticalCSS adds another  tag to add the new CSS
2. If html is removed/no longer criticalCSS the css is left inplace.

My only goal is to do the following:

Detect a line starting with:  and ending with 
Remove the line (i prefer to have this in batch, but if someone suggests to do this in python/etc). That's also ok.

I hope someone is able to help me with this, and maybe even point out source material for me to look into to learn more!

I try to delete this kind of internal CSS: https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L135
But want to keep this
https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L11
up to
https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L134

So that for example:

```
<style>
bal bla bla
</style>
```

is intact
but
`<style>bal bla bla</style>`
is removed

Answer (score -2, accepted):

> My only goal is to do the following:
>
> Detect a line starting with: `<style>` and ending with `</style>`
> Remove the line

> So that for example:
>
> ```
> <style>
>  bal bla bla
> </style>
> ```
>
> is intact but
>
> ```
> <style>bal bla bla</style>
> ```
>
> is removed

If you use [`sed`](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sed), you have to ensure that a delimiter character which is part of the address expression is prepended with `\`:

```
sed -i '/<style>.*<\/style>$/d' file
```

Comment: i'm terrible sorry for responding so late firstly.
I need to add more information, as it doesn't sadly work yet!
I try to delete this kind of internal CSS: https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L135
But want to keep this
https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L11
up to
https://github.com/Macleykun/criticaltest/blob/main/404.html#L134

Comment: So that for example:
<style>
bal bla bla
</style> 
(this is multi lined!)
is intact but
<style>bal bla bla</style>
is removed

Comment: It's even more simple then - the line actually isn't _starting with: `<style>`_ (but rather with spaces), so we just have to remove the anchor `^`.

Comment: Thank you so, so much! It indeeds removes the internal CSS and leaves the multi lined CSS intact with it's tags!
Thank you for your time and incredible wisdom! I wish i was this good with scripting/sed! It's truely amazing in my eyes!